# Spring Roo with 512MB memory limit

Tags: java, spring-mvc, heroku, spring-roo

Are there any tricks I can use in order to stop my Spring Roo app from constantly exceeding the memory limit in Heroku?
 Even the standard petclinic app https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-spring-mvc-hibernate is constantly crashing.

Comment: What do you have `-Xmx` set to now? It defaults to 350m on a Heroku Free/Hobby/1X dyno (with 512mb of RAM). But you can set this down to `-Xmx300m` or even lower.

Comment: Thank you, -Xmx300m works fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating what's in the comments so it can be accepted as an answer:

Try setting `Xmx` lower than the default 350m by running:

```
$ heroku config:set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx300m"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change it on a Spring application. This is a application container matters: application uses the memory which requires.

There only way to earn memory is reduce the application footprint by reduce dependencies which can be optional. This can be archive managing maven dependencies in `pom.xml`, but is just a try-catch job.

Good luck!